# Does the phrase, “come, let’s make sweet music together” have the same impact in Spanish?

Tags: expresiones

I want to use this phrase with a person I am romantically involved with; we are also both musicians.

Does it have the same impact in Spanish? Is there a better/more common way to write it? I found this on Google Translate: “ven, hagamos música dulce juntos.”

Thanks for any advice you can give!

Comment: You could also say "música romántica", depending on what the intended impact is...

Comment: @wimi Which coincidently is the title of a popular love song ;)

Comment: I’m not entirely sure this phrase would have the intended impact in English, TBH. It’s pretty old-fashioned/quaint

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. It wouldn't have the impact it has in English. It's an english phrase and it does not exists in Spanish.

If you translate it as:

> Ven, hagamos música dulce juntos

it will be confusing. So it won't have impact at all. Here you have a range of interpretations of the listener:

- do you want sex?
- do you wanna marry me?
- do you want me to play piano tonight?
- do you want to play karaoke?
- etc.

He/She won't understand it and the most probably answer you'll receive is: "¿Qué?". It doesn't sound bad, but nobody will understand "To have a great romantic relationship with each other" (https://www.phrases.com/phrase/make-beautiful-music-together_26073).